# PHP action when more than one checkbox was selected

Tags: php, if-statement, checkbox

I've got a POST form with its action on the same page. The form has many checkboxes and I'd like run some PHP line when the user has checked more than one checkbox (PHP should run after submitting the form).

So basically I'd need following in PHP:

If checked checkboxes of #FormXY > 1
...do something...
else (which means 0 or 1 checked checbox)
...do something else

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: This site is for programming questions. it is NOT a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes are submitted to POST only if they are checked. So, simplest way:

```
<?php

  $checks = 0;

  if ( isset($_POST['checkbox_1']) ) $checks++;
  if ( isset($_POST['checkbox_2']) ) $checks++;
  if ( isset($_POST['checkbox_3']) ) $checks++;
  // ... for every checkbox name ...

  if ($checks > 1)
  {
     // Do something
  }

  else
  {
     // Do something else
  }

?>
```

If checkboxes names are incremental, you can play with cycles, like this:

```
<?php

  $checks = 0;

  for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
  {
     if ( isset($_POST["checkbox_{$i}"]) ) $checks++;
  }

  if ($checks > 1)
  {
     // Do something
  }

  else
  {
     // Do something else
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$chkcount = 0;
  if (isset($_POST['check1'])) && ($_POST['check1']){ ++$chkcount;}
  if (isset($_POST['check2'])) && ($_POST['check2']){ ++$chkcount;}
....
  if (isset($_POST['check9'])) && ($_POST['check9']){ ++$chkcount;}
if ($chkcount > 1){ 
    // multiple checkboxes checked
   } else {
  // one or zero checked
 }
```